# getting the latest item of the pivot relationship

Tags: laravel, relation

I have a pivot relationship as below:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'pet_owners','pet_id','owner_id');
}
```

now in my controller i want to get the latest item of this pivot table which is sorted by created_at field . here is how i get it now :

```
$pets = Pet::with('users')->get();
return new PetResource($pets);
```

here I want to show all pets with the latest user entered for that pet in the pivot table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limiting eager loads is unfortunately not easily done with Eloquent. There are many issues related to this on the Github repo. You can read [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4835) thread for an overview.

One of Laravel's contributors released a package [staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit) to make it easier to limit eager loads. You can install it with:

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit:"^1.0"
```

You need to add the `\Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;` trait to both your `Pet` and `User` models. Then you'll be able to use the `limit` method on a query inside a `with` method on your model:

```
$pets = Pet::with(['users' => function ($query) {
   return $query->latest()->limit(1);
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way,

```
    $pets = Pet::whereHas('users', function($q){
        $q->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
    })->get();
    return new PetResource($pets);
    // return latest record of pivot table
```

Comment: Yes i tried this way but i get this error :message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `pets` where exists (select * from `users` inner join `pet_owners` on `users`.`id` = `pet_owners`.`owner_id` where `pets`.`id` = `pet_owners`.`pet_id` order by `created_at` desc) limit 1)",

Comment: its because both tables have the created_at field

Comment: @Farshad try using my updated answer, and if both fields have created_at but where has only refers to the pivot table.

Comment: You're just returning the first pet that has any users here. The OP's asking how to return all pets with their latest user attached.

Comment: @Farshad in that case you need to give your id in descending order i have updated my answer.